# Preventing Line Breaking in Middle of Word in Android XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to prevent line spacing unless it makes sense to break the line there. For some reason, on devices with smaller screens, there is a forced line break. EX:

```
TITLE

CAPTION
```

vs

```
TITLE
CAP
TION
```

I set the min lines to 2 to standardize spacing, because there are some instances where the text does need to flow to the second line. It just doesn't always. It works fine on devices with larger screens.

my xml for the caption text view i am trying to standardize:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/someid"
            style="@style/CaptionText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

I have tried adding `android:hyphenationFrequency` and `android:breakStrategy` and had no luck with either.

Reiterating that I want there to be a minimum line of 2, otherwise the elements in the list are staggered.

Comment: Try using `AutoResizeTextView` libraries or playing with `android:lineSpacingExtra`

Answer (score 0):

okay so if anyone cares:

```
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/some_id"
            style="@style/CaptionText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_text"
             />
```

the fix was to add missing constraints and change width to 0dp since constraint is now from start to end of parent